# Windows 10 search not "popping up"

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

(Using Windows 10 Pro x64)

Hi

When I click the "search icon" in the taskbar, nothing happens - no popup window.

When I click the start button in the taskbar a window popsup ... fine .. but if I start to type to filter programs, nothing happens.

I've tried this...

```
Press Windows + X keys on the keyboard, select Command prompt (admin).
Enter the below commands one by one and hit Enter key.
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
It will open the PowerShell window.
Now enter the below command and hit Enter key.
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers |Where-Object {$_.InstallLocation -like "*SystemApps*"} | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

Didn't help - any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Try: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/cortana-taskbar-search-not-working-in-windows-10